Blending equation for layer mask (alpha channel included)
Suppose I have a three images, two rgba images A and B (with premultiplied alpha), and one grayscale image, M. How to implement the OVER operator in this case?

Lerping using only M. That is, out = A*(1 - M) + B*M
Multiply the alpha in B with M, and then apply the over operator. That is, out = B + A*(1 - B.a*M)


how is the "over" operator defined? in which of your equations do you use it? how are all the identifiers in the right hand sides of your equations defined?
